# Excel Form Control Oddity With Respect To Clearing Filters

Tags: excel, user-controls, excel-2010

I will first say that I have already posted this question on a different forum, here:

http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/1072528-form-control-oddity-with-respect-to-clearing-filters.html

though, not having as yet received any replies, I am hoping that someone here may be able to help me. I will reiterate here what I have posted there, viz:

I have a simple table, one column of which contains Form Controls (Option or "Radio" Buttons, to be precise), one for each row in the table, all of them having their property set to "Move and Size with Cells".

This is fine and good, since I can sort the table as desired and these objects remain in their respective rows.

However, I've just noticed an issue re filtering in this table. Filtering a column is fine, as is removing that filter, *but only if the latter is done via the Clear Filter option within the drop-down itself*. If I instead choose to use the *Clear* option in the *Sort & Filter* group within the *Data* tab, then the radio buttons in any rows which were not part of that filter (i.e. were hidden) are not correctly resized.

For example, if you access the attached file at the link provided (sorry - I am unsure if I can post files on this site) and try filtering on column E (Assigned?) for "No". Then see the results of removing the filter the two different ways that I describe.

Strangely, any sensible operation will rectify this, e.g. just changing the row height for a single row (it doesn't even have to be changed to anything different - the operation itself is sufficient). Or just simply going into one of the filters and clicking on OK but without actually selecting anything and coming straight back out.

What is happening here? How can it be remedied?

Many thanks for any input.

Regards